# Create a REST API client for android using Okhttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I am planning to redesign my REST API client class. I am using Okhttp for making API calls and here is how my current API client class looks like.

My API Client class:

```
public class NetworkUtil {

private final String API_ENDPOINT_ONE = "https://api/endpoint/1";
private final String API_ENDPOINT_TWO = "https://api/endpoint/2";

public static void getData(String url, final OkHttpListener listener){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    // GET request
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(API_ENDPOINT_ONE)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            listener.onFailure(request, e);
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            listener.onResponse(response);
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my callback interface:

```
public interface OkHttpListener {
    void onFailure(Request request, IOException e);
    void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException;
}
```

I have many API endpoints. I need to design this class in such a way that I can send JSON requests and get the response from the Activity/Fragment itself.

Comment: Have you looked at [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)?

Comment: @Jack, are there any examples using Retrofit. There are a lot of tutorials on Retrofit but I am not able to find anything related my issue

Comment: I'm not really sure what your issues is, you're planning to redesign your app api layer? You can use Retrofit to do that.

Comment: Yes, I want to redesign the API layer, but how do I do it using retrofit? are there any examples or git repositories that I can have a look at?

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: @Jack, Thanks, let me have a look at it

Comment: Do you develop the API  (server code) directly?

Comment: @localhost if you are developing the sever side code directly I suggest you to take a look ad swagger: https://swagger.io/ Having a swagger definition of your server API could let you able to automatically generate the client side code.